# How to prove forall x, (R x \/ ~ R x) [in the Coq proof assistant]?

Tags: coq, proof

How does one prove `forall x, (R x \/ ~R x)` in Coq. I'm a noob at this and don't know much of this tool. 
This is what I wrote:

```
Variables D: Set.
Variables R: D -> Prop.
Variables x:D.

Lemma tes : forall x, (R x \/ ~R x).
```

I tried this and it worked, but only in auto mode. And if I print the proof I cannot understand the meaning of what's printed (so I can go back and try to do it not in auto mode):

```
Require Import Classical.

Variables D: Set.
Variables R: D -> Prop.
Variables x:D.

Lemma tes : forall x, (R x \/ ~R x).
Proof.
intro.
tauto.
Qed.

Print tes.

tes = 
fun x0 : D =>
NNPP (R x0 \/ ~ R x0)
  (fun H : ~ (R x0 \/ ~ R x0) =>
   (fun H0 : R x0 -> False =>
    (fun H1 : ~ R x0 -> False =>
     (fun H2 : False => False_ind False H2) (H1 H0))
      (fun H1 : ~ R x0 => H (or_intror H1)))
     (fun H0 : R x0 => H (or_introl H0)))
     : forall x : D, R x \/ ~ R x
```

Comment: Are you asking somebody to explain the proof term?  If so, you should edit your question to provide a better title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to prove it would be

```
Print classic.
Print R.
Print x.
Check R x.
Check classic (R x).
Check fun y => classic (R y).

Definition tes2 : forall x, (R x \/ ~ R x) := fun y => classic (R y).
```

Or using tactics

```
Lemma tes3 : forall x, (R x \/ ~ R x). Proof. intro. apply classic. Qed.

Print tes3.
```

The proof `tauto` found was

```
Lemma tes : forall x, (R x \/ ~R x).
Proof.
intro.
eapply NNPP.
intro.
assert (R x0 -> False).
intro.
eapply H.
eapply or_introl.
exact H0.
assert (~ R x0 -> False).
intro.
eapply H.
eapply or_intror.
exact H1.
assert False.
eapply H1.
exact H0.
eapply False_ind.
exact H2.
Qed.
```

The `intro` tactic builds lambda abstractions, and performs implication introduction and universal quantification introduction, the `apply` tactic combines previously proven theorems, and performs modus ponens where the first antecedent has already been proven, the `exact` tactic gives the exact proof term, and the `assert` tactic also performs modus ponens where none of the antecedents of the rule are given. To see how tactics manipulate the proof term use the `Show Proof` command before and after applying a tactic.